# Reporting shadow prices from SimplexSolver

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I'm using the [SimplexSolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.solvers.simplexsolver.aspx) class directly to solve a linear program, with AddRow, AddVariable and SetCoefficient. This works quite well.

We need to come up with shadow prices now, and I don't see any way to access either the shadow prices or the simplex matrix.

If I set [SimpleSolverParams.GetSensitivityReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.solvers.simplexsolverparams.getsensitivityreport.aspx) to true, casting the return of [SimplexSolver.GetReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff525231.aspx) to ILinearSolverSensitivityReport may be the key here. Checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [ILinearSolverSensitivityReport.GetDualValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.ilinearsolversensitivityreport.getdualvalue.aspx) returns the shadow price.

Hopefully this saves someone else a merry chase through dotPeek. :-)